# Are these number of threads in a process normal?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When my asp.net application starts, i got around 40 threads associated in a process. Is this normal? Sorry for the noob question. The actual threads running (state) depends on the core of my machine. For example, in running in 4 cores pc, im getting around 1-4 Running threads (parallel) and the total number of threads in a process is around 38-42. When running the application in 24 cores pc, im still getting around 38-42 threads.

My Code for getting the number of running threads:

```
((IEnumerable)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
                .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
                .Count()
```

Code for getting the total number of threads:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

Can someone please explain this to a noob like me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, sometimes i am getting around 90 threads associated in a process during peak of a parallel tasks in a 24 core machine. But after a long parallel processing is complete, the number of threads will go back to  around 42.

Comment: Your CurrentProcess is IIS. And yes it is normal for IIS to have a handful of threads at a minimum.

Comment: Hi Henk! Thanks for the quick response. Do you mean that the total number of threads that i'm getting using the above code is not generated solely by my application?

Comment: I just tried to answer but I noticed that there is no real question. What *is* your question? Is there something unclear? Everything makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ASP.NET site is running in an [Application Pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735247%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which will have a certain number of threads and may spawn more if needed. Each request is handled in a separate thread so IIS will keep some threads waiting for a request, because it is faster to use existing thread than to start a new one when needed.

IIS will also have spare threads in [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5htx827.aspx) for your application to use.

So yes, it is normal for IIS to have multiple threads.

Comment: Hi Ilari Mäkimattila, the thing that I don't understand is that if there are around 40 threads in my current process, why is that the number of threads is increasing up to 90 threads if there are only 24 cores in my machine. Is the 40 threads not enough for 24 threads (cores)? Why do IIS threadpool keep creating new threads?

Comment: It's not necessarily the thread pool spawning new processes. The IIS worker is probably the one creating them. It pools the threads simply because it is cheaper to have them lying around than creating a new one on demand. It might never actually need all of them.